# Wcf Service push notification to xamarin client

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin, cross-platform

How I can send push notification from wcf service to xamarin android(iOS) client without sending request from client to service?

Comment: you could vote it or discuss:[Request add WCF Duplex Channel support for Mono(for Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS)](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=41392)

Answer (score 0):

Sending a Push-Notification from your wcf Service to a Client without a request can be done by using wcf callbacks. Here are 2 Links on how to implement it:

[Push Data to client](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/wcf/721/push-data-wcf-callback-service)

[A simple WCF Service Callback](http://adamprescott.net/2012/08/15/a-simple-wcf-service-callback-example/)

Comment: Thanks of lot. Are you sure what your link's example will be work with xamarin mobile client?

Comment: i'm not sure as i've never used xamarin mobile Client but i'm using wcf callbacks at work and it is working. You have to use a Duplex channel for the callbacks but that should be no Problem